# Noninferiority test for nonparametric distributions -- which statistical test to use?

Tags: nonparametric, equivalence, non-inferiority

I'm trying to conduct a noninferiority test to determine whether one treatment is no worse than another. The distributions of the two populations are likely not normal, so I want to use a non-parametric test. What statistical test should I choose, and how can I implement it in R? Thank you in advance for your help -- I'm a relative beginner when it comes to stats!

Comment: "[Parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics)" does not mean normal (it means having a fixed, finite number of unspecified parameters) and conversely for nonparametric, which doesn't mean "non-normal" it means something like "not parametric". If you mean something is non-normal (per your title), just say that.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the two treatments are significantly different. If they are, you look at which one is better and you have answered your question.

For testing the significance of the difference of the treatments, you first have to decide whether you are doing [paired difference testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) or not. For paired data, that is not normal, popular tests are McNemar, sign test, or Wilcoxon's signed-rank test. For unpaired data, check out Mann–Whitney U test or the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test. There are lots of others, always check the preconditions for application. All of them have implementations in R; just google to get a tutorial that goes with your test.

Comment: The problem is that here, the null hypothesis is that the treatments are different, and the test hypothesis is that they are comparable. Failing to find a significant difference between the two treatments in the situation you're describing is not the same as proving that they are comparable to a statistically significant degree. https://pubs.rsna.org/doi/full/10.1148/radiol.12120725

Comment: For a hypothesis test, you need to define the null hypothesis. If the null is that the resulting distributions are equal, this is easy to define: both distributions are of the same type with the same parameters. If you say that the null is that the distributions are different, you have to define what you mean by this. Equivalently, you have to define what it means that they are comparable.